# Rails 6 ActiveRecord sum columns in where clause

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rails-activerecord

I have a Rails 6 app and a tabele with a `scheduled_at` and a `duration` (in minutes) column.

I want to get all records where `scheduled_at + duration.minutes > Time.current`.

Ideally I would have an `ends_at` columns, but unfortunately I don't.

Is there a way how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `interval` of postgresql then add 1 minute multiplied by your duration

```rb
Record.where("(scheduled_at + INTERVAL '1' MINUTE * duration) > ?", Time.current)
```

Make sure your duration is an integer tho

Answer (score 1):

You can make use of the `INTERVAL` method in Postgres and compare that to the current time with `NOW`

```rb
Model.where("scheduled_at + INTERVAL '? minutes' > NOW()", 10)

# or ...
Model.where("scheduled_at + INTERVAL '? minutes' > ?", 10, Time.current)
```

Comment: I assume that the 10 is the number of minutes? In my example the number of minutes is in the 'duration' column.

Comment: Yeah, you might be able to do `scheduled_at + (duration || ' minutes')::interval > NOW()`

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function [`make_interval`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/functions-datetime.html) to create an interval from a column value (or any integer really):

```
Model.where(
   "scheduled_at + make_interval(mins := models.duration::INTEGER) > current_timestamp" 
)

# Or if you want to use your Rails servers notion of "now":
Model.where(
   "scheduled_at + make_interval(mins := models.duration::INTEGER) > ?", Time.current 
)
```

`:=` is the Postgres syntax for [named notation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/sql-syntax-calling-funcs.html) which is similiar to keyword arguments in Ruby.

If you want to have a `ends_at` in the result you can select it:

```
Model
 .select(
   Model.arel_table[:*],
   "scheduled_at + make_interval(mins := models.duration::INTEGER) AS ends_at" 
 )
 .where(
   "ends_at > current_timestamp" 
 )
```